# RecaptchaState is not defined

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, recaptcha

I read the same question on stackoverflow but it doesn't solve my problem.

RecaptchaState is not defined error is because http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k='.CAPPUBKEY.'">

in this link they defined RecaptchaState variable.at end of file they write

```
document.write('recaptcha.js');
```

which creates the problem.

This line loads recaptcha.js to a new page so all previous code is gone and it can't get recaptchastate or any other previous html.

I'm doing all the process using recaptcha ajax.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem is because the Recaptcha key hasn't been sent to the Recaptcha API.

Make sure the API key is defined somewhere that gets the value before calling the API. If you have a server code but the API call is in a js file, it might not be running therefore the API key will be empty.

You can always try first hard coding the API key to see if still fails, for example:

```
Recaptcha.destroy();
Recaptcha.create("xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx", "captcha", {});
```